# Why do I have to reconnect to localhost:3000 in a new window?

Tags: c++, node.js, google-chrome, websocket, localhost

I have written a program that when running, I can connect to using localhost:3000 in browser (chrome). Periodically when debugging the WebSocket Connection fails:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/serv/socketio/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

My issue is that when I restart the program and try to reconnect I cannot simply refresh the page. If I just try to refresh the page it will continue to print out the WebSocket connection failed message. I have to open a new window. Why is this and is there a fix?

Edit: I have tested in IE and I can refresh the page with no issues. IE will connect back up to localhost:3000 with no WebSocket Disconnect Failure

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I do not have an issue with my code, I am asking about why I need to open a new tab or window in google chrome in order to connect back to localhost rather than just refreshing the page. What does opening a new instance of a chrome page have to do with the ability to connect to localhost?

Comment: Unfortunately I have far to much code to upload. I could upload my WebSocketManager.js but there is not an issue with it. I just need to know about how chrome works. Thanks!

Comment: its depend on your connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive ran into funny issues like this when debugging sockets with specifically web browsers. I'm sure there is a magic answer for this, but my hand wavy answer is that in my experience the browsers try to be smart and remember the fact that a socket doesn't work, as well as many other things about the information they expect to receive, etc. They're not very responsive to changes in state. This applies to many things, much less whether or not they can establish a TCP connection. For example, CSS caching and the like...

All of this is done to try to save some internet bandwidth. i.e. make 'reasonable assumptions' and download less things per page load. Of course, those assumptions are built on the premise that you are doing regular web browsing.

So just open a new window long story short.

Using a private browsing window may also help.

Comment: I tried using private browsing and checked "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" but still am not having any luck.